# How can I bind an App registration to a specific Power BI instance?

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have two app registrations for two different projects in Azure Active Directory. I also created two Power BI Embedded instances. I only have access to a single subscription in this account. Is there a way to assign a single instance for each app?

Comment: so you created the 2 pbi instances in the single/same subscription? and want to assign the app reg 1 to 1st pbi embed instance and app reg 2 to 2nd pbi embed instance ?
Also when you say 2 different project you mean those 2 app reg is created on 2 different AAD Tenant ?

Comment: @Jayendran exactly: there are "2 pbi instances in the same subscription" and I do "want to assign the app reg 1 to 1st pbi embed instance and app reg 2 to 2nd pbi embed instance". But when I say they are 2 different projects, I'm just saying that they will be used by different applications. They are both in the same AAD Tenant.

Comment: Looks like an easy configuration to me. You can assign each app/SPN as the `Power BI capacity administrator` respectively. Is there any particular issue you are facing?

Comment: @Jayendran thank you. Previously none of the app registrations were `Power BI capacity administrator` on any of the instances and my dashboards were rendering when I embedded then. I just configured the first one as `Power BI capacity administrator` on a single PBI instance. Is there any way I can verify it's using the correct instance?

Comment: Update: I paused the instance and the embedded reports are still rendering so I guess it didn't work

Comment: Assigning `PBI capacity admin` gives you the ability to assign that capacity to a pbi workspace. If you want to test the capacity you can even add your name as the capacity admin and assign that particular capacity to your workspace- [Reference](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/How-to-apply-Power-BI-Embedded-capacity-to-workspace/m-p/473924). I'm not sure about your use case/Why you need SPN with the pbi capacity

Comment: @Jayendran sorry for taking so long to reply. I was experimenting with it and separating a workspace for each application and assigning PBI capacity to it instead of an service principal solved the problem for my use case. I think it might be helpful for people struggling with similar issues to post a reply to this question. Do you want to post one so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PBI embedded capacity resources in azure, you can add/remove users/SPNs(apps) as `PBI capacity Administrator`.

PBI capacity Admin gives you the ability to assign that PBI capacity to a workspace.

*e.g, If you are given the capacity admin, then you can assign that capacity to any workspace in which you are part of the admin. You can achieve the same thing for SPNs using REST APIs*

For more details on how to use the Capacity you can [refer here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/How-to-apply-Power-BI-Embedded-capacity-to-workspace/m-p/473924)